# about the FIRPMORD function---fir filter design related

Tags: matlab

I have run into a little problem concerning matlab function `FIRPMORD`. Because the output from this particular function doesn't really meet the specification, so can I add the order of this result by 5 manually? I know we can add the odder up by 1 or 2, but I am just not quite sure can we actually increase it beyond 2...

Thanks a lot!!! looking forward to your reply!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same question, you can see my post address.
Normally, add 1 or 2 will meet the specification, as the firpmord.m said.